# For a certain value of $p$, point $T_p$ lies on the line $y=2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just can't wrap my ahead around some of these questions.

> For $p>0$ we define the family of functions $f_p$ by $f_p(x)=-\frac{2}{3}x^3+px^3$
>
> For a certain value of $p$ point $T_p (p, \frac{1}{3}p^3$) lies on the line $y=2x$.

At the beginning I thought well, equal them to each other and find out where they meet. That doesn't work, because we have 2 variables. Apparently the answer is to replace $x$ by $p$, which is $\frac{1}{3}p^3$=$2p$.

I don't understand, why did they replace $x$ by $p$? Where do they get the idea that they will only be meeting at $x=p$? I also don't quite understand the whole "for a certain value of xyz" in a multivariable equation. I would really like to get an intuition, would someone be some kind and help me out?

Comment: Any point of the line $y=2x$ can be written as $(x,2x),$ $(a,2a)$ or $(p,2p).$

Comment: Does that mean we can just take $p$, and say it has to equal to $x$ thus replace it? Aren't they distinguished?

Comment: $(x,2x)$ ia a generic point of the line. If you want $T_p$ to be in the line you need to check that the second coordinate $1/3p^3$ is the double of the first one $p.$

Comment: $x$ is a variable, and $p$ is a numerical value. So just like you can plug in e.g. $5$ for $x$, by the same token you can plug in $p$ for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two equations:

$$ (x,y)=\left(p,\frac{1}{3}p^3\right) \quad\text{ad}\quad y=2x. $$

It follows that

$$ \underset{y}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{3}p^3}} = 2\underset{x}{\underbrace{p}} .$$

Comment: I read the comments yet I can't get it in, why is $p$=$x$? I thought these are two distinguished values.

Comment: When you say that $(a,b)$ is a point in the $xy$-axis, it means that $x=a$ and $y=b$.

Comment: so in this case, $p$ is actually $x$ (The variable, which we can deduct from it being labeled in the form $(x,y)$? This confused me because it's $T_p(x)$ not $T(p)$

Comment: Yes. Sorry, but I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Well I thought the $x$ in a $(x,y)$ coordinate can only equal the x as in the $variable$, so I threated it as such, but I forgot that the variable is actually $p$, the numerical value. Thank you, I wouldn't have understood it without your explanation.